# Requests with json payload freezes at > 64Kb

Tags: python, json, request

Subject: Python, requests with json payload freezes at > 64Kb

On ubuntu linux with requests 2.3

```
for-loop:
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    results = response.json()
```

Code works but fails when payload > 64Kb and program freezes.  Using pudb, isolated problem to:

```
Traceback
    File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476 in readline
      data = self._socket.recv(self._rbufsize)

Variables:
  buf: StringIO
  buf_len: 0
  self: _fileobject
  size: 65537

Stack:
  readline [_fileobject] socket.py
  _read_status [HTTPResponse] httplib.py
  begin [HTTPResponse] httplib.py
  getresponse [HTTPConnection]
  _make_request [HTTPConnectionpool]
  urlopen [HTTPConnectionpool]
  send [HTTPAdaptor] adapters.py
  send [Session] sessions.py:486
  request [Session] sessions.py
  request api.py:44
  post api.py:88
```

It seems as if a buffer isn't being cleared.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: That line is *waiting for the socket to receive data*. The socket is blocked, not the buffer.

Comment: At the point of your trace, the *server* is hanging. The full request has been sent to the server, and is now waiting for the server to respond for a `HTTP/1.1 <status code> <status message>` status line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests` has uploaded the request *just fine*. It is the *server* that is not responding.

The specific line is waiting for data from the socket; `self._socket.recv(self._rbufsize)` means *read up to `self._rbufsize` number of bytes* from the socket.

From your trace, it is clear this is being called from the `HTTPResponse._read_status` line, which is trying to read the [HTTP response status line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html); e.g. it is waiting for the server to send it back the `HTTP 1.1 200 OK` or similar response-received line.

You'll need to figure out why your server apparently cannot handle requests over 64KB. Python requests has done all it can to upload the request already.

Comment: Thanks so much as it helps to isolate. It was either requests or wekzeug on the server. tried werkzeug with 3 different http servers - run_simple (which comes with werzeug), gevent.pywsgi and tornado - and the outcome is the same. Trouble is that I've not been able to isolate the problem to specific code on the server.

Comment: Try isolating your client from your server. What happens when you post to `http://httpbin.org/post` for example? That's an echo server, see http://httpbin.org/ for (some) documentation.

Comment: Are there any firewalls or routers on your network? If it hangs for httpbin as well, does posting to the SSL version of the site make a difference? What happens when you use a different network to post the data?